# How to correctly implement dropout for convolution in TensorFlow

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network

According to the original paper on Dropout said regularisation method can be applied to convolution layers often improving their performance. TensorFlow function `tf.nn.dropout` supports that by having a `noise_shape` parameter to allow the user to choose which parts of the tensors will drop out independently. However, neither the paper nor the documentation give a clear explanation of which dimensions should be kept independently, and the TensorFlow explanation of how `noise_shape` works is rather unclear.

> only dimensions with noise_shape[i] == shape(x)[i] will make independent decisions.

I would assume that for a typical CNN layer output of the shape `[batch_size, height, width, channels]` we don't want individual rows or columns to drop out by themselves, but rather whole channels (which would be equivalent to a node in a fully connected NN) independently of the examples (i.e. different channels could be dropped for different examples in a batch). Am I correct in this assumption?

If so, how would one go about implementing dropout with such specificity using the `noise_shape` parameter? Would it be:

```
noise_shape=[batch_size, 1, 1, channels]
```

or:

```
noise_shape=[1, height, width, 1]
```

Comment: I am not entirely sure that it is standard to drop entire channels. I have read different things different places, and it seems to me that many drop individual elements (skalars) independently, i.e. leave `noise_shape` as default.

Comment: What you are doing is called spatial dropouts ([SO post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/147850/are-pooling-layers-added-before-or-after-dropout-layers/225873?noredirect=1#comment612222_225873), [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.4280.pdf)). It seems to me that the standard dropout, even for conv layers, is each element independently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dropout),

> For example, if shape(x) = [k, l, m, n] and noise_shape = [k, 1, 1, n], each batch and channel component will be kept independently and each row and column will be kept or not kept together.

The code may help explain this.

```
noise_shape = noise_shape if noise_shape is not None else array_ops.shape(x)
# uniform [keep_prob, 1.0 + keep_prob)
random_tensor = keep_prob
random_tensor += random_ops.random_uniform(noise_shape,
                                           seed=seed,
                                           dtype=x.dtype)
# 0. if [keep_prob, 1.0) and 1. if [1.0, 1.0 + keep_prob)
binary_tensor = math_ops.floor(random_tensor)
ret = math_ops.div(x, keep_prob) * binary_tensor
ret.set_shape(x.get_shape())
return ret
```

the line `random_tensor +=` supports [broadcast](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html). When the noise_shape[i] is set to 1, that means all elements in this dimension will add the same random value ranged from 0 to 1. So when `noise_shape=[k, 1, 1, n]`, each row and column in the feature map will be kept or not kept together. On the other hand, each example (batch) or each channel receives different random values and each of them will be kept independently.